# How to perform the following: Join

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two tables into the final one as seen in the figure below.

[image]

How can I do this in pandas? What type of join is this called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df1.merge(df2, on="grid_id", how="outer")`

(See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html))

If you want, read [the full explanation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) on `.concat()`, `.merge()`, and `.join()`.